# website not loading the updated css files

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, cloudflare, css

I have been using cloudflare for almost all of my projects and i've been trying to set it up for my new project but there is a really strange problem i'm facing.

so when i update `.css` files from the server the changes don't get effected when i load them on website, and i know for sure that it's not a caching thing because i tried clear caching/incognito and even had my fried test it.

and if this is not weird enough this not updating problem only happens for `.css` files. other formats work perfectly fine.

and this is why it made me thinking that it might be something from cloudflare: check out this link with http and https: http://fleats.club/style/aa.css. it display different thing for each of them, http one was a file that i deleted but it still loads on http! and the https one is a new one file with same name i created with a different characters in it and i changed the characters in it but it still displays the old characters (old characters: "saaa")

nginx:

```
  listen 80;

  server_name fleats.club;

  root /srv/main/site;

  location / {
      index index.html;
  }
}
```

this might sound like a human mistake but i've been looking every where but can't figure this out.
any idea what could possibly cause this? i have no clue really,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and i know for sure that it's not a caching thing because i tried clear caching/incognito and even had my fried test it.

Have you done Cloudflare cache cleaning? 
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169246-Purging-cached-resources-from-Cloudflare

[image]

if the development goes on and testing needs to be continuous you can consider `development mode`. 
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168246-Understanding-Cloudflare-Development-Mode

[image]

Comment: oh i didn't know u can clear cache on cloudflare side! clear caching cloudflare worked but it worked for on time and i had to clear cache every time from cloudflare. i activated development mode and now it's working fine and updating the files every time but i can't leave the development mode On for always though (right?), and i guess the solution is not to manually clear cache every time i make a change on the css files, so what is the permanent solution?

Comment: also why this is happening? it never happened for my old projects. and the stranger thing is that it only happens for .css files!

Comment: Cloudflare is ment to cache and save bandwidth. Thats the whole purpose of cdn. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network . Use development mode until you complete testing. Regarding your othersites, cant predict cloudflare algo , regarding caching.

Comment: Also please dont forget to mark it as the answer

Comment: done thank you very much